# Node cannot start due to `exitOnParametersMismatch`

Tags: corda

I have registered a node with an existing Corda network. When I then try to start the node, I get the following exception:

> E 15:32:20+0530 [Network Map Updater Thread-1]
>   network.NetworkMapUpdater.exitOnParametersMismatch - Node is using
>   parameters with hash:
>   6C174011FD30DB2921E2595C927C49035C1287C313F557C69653A2019B04B803 but
>   network map is advertising:
>   12693BBBBF3BB89543FA7B08B31F0DC619DA4798DAF571659E2FBD2731415D61. Node
>   will shutdown now. Please update node to use correct network
>   parameters file. {}

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the node had an old `network-parameters` file lying around in its directory from another network.

I simply deleted the existing `network-parameters` file and restarted the node. It then downloaded the network parameters of the new network automatically and started normally.